# How to run `docker` service if no space left on device?

Tags: docker

I have configured `"data-root": "/mnt/docker-overlay"` and my `/mnt/docker-overlay` volume does not have space.

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb         40G   40G     0 100% /mnt/docker-overlay
```

I can not run `docker system prune` or similar, because docker service was exited due to space issue.

How to run `docker` service back and perform cleanup?

Comment: Is `/dev/sdb` a virtual disk by any chance? (40GB is an odd shape for a physical disk) ... are you able to resize / extend the filesystem? (even if only temporarily)

Comment: This is a `volume` ordered on hosting provider. Yes, I am  able, but it will costs some money.

Comment: Alternatively, are you able to identify some volumes with disposable data? (I don't know how upset docker will get if you go removing entire volumes, but I'd imagine it wouldn't be too concerned about some of the content going missing)

Answer (score 1):

I found this workaround:
Detect which container consumes space and why. In my case I cleaned up log file

```
# cd /mnt/docker-overlay/containers
# du -h -d 1
# cd ./b16..zx
# ls -la
total 7207732
drwx--x---  4 root root       4096 May 27  2023 .
drwx--x--- 33 root root       4096 Jan 26  2023 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root root 7380619264 Dec 21 03:28 b16..zx-json.log
drwx------  2 root root       4096 Jan 16  2023 checkpoints
-rw-------  1 root root       4651 May 27  2023 config.v2.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       1594 May 27  2023 hostconfig.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         13 May 27  2023 hostname
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        177 May 27  2023 hosts
drwx--x---  2 root root       4096 Jan 16  2023 mounts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         53 May 27  2023 resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         71 May 27  2023 resolv.conf.hash

# : > b16..zx-json.log
```

Though this is very strange that it consumes so much disk space, despite I limited logs only to 500m.

```
# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "debug": true,
  "data-root": "/mnt/docker-overlay",
  "features":
    { "buildkit": true },
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "500m",
    "max-file": "5"
  }
}
```

**UPD**
Important notice: after changing logging options we MUST recreate existing containers. Otherwise they will continue to eat disk space:
[comment1](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1148#issuecomment-729539456) and [comment2](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1148#issuecomment-645990725)

Check that your containers uses correct option: `docker inspect <container-name> | grep -B 0 -A 6 LogConfig`

Comment: This is a good solution - well done! Log config can be overridden for each container, so it's worth checking how it's set for the one you truncated.

Comment: @Attie: I also found the reason why a disk space was consumed despite on `max-size` configuration.